# LaTeX Error: Environment longtable undefined

Tags: environments, longtable, overleaf, mac, appendix

I've been trying to create long tables for my thesis. Everytime I compile I get errors that prevent the creation of a PDF view. Here's the code:

```
\begin{longtable}{lllllllll}
\caption{Table A.1: Poggio Civitate (dataset from the Carta Archeologica della Provincia di Siena. Vol. 5, Vo. 8, Vol. 12)}\\
Id  & Type         & Chron. 1   & Chron. 2   & q & LO/Av      & Cv  & Source\_id & Source             \endfirsthead
1   & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 101        & Campana 2013, 86   \\
2   & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 102        & Campana 2013, 86   \\
3   & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 101        & Campana 2013, 86   \\
4   & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 102        & Campana 2013, 86   \\
5   & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 10         & Campana 2001, 135  \\
6   & House        & 630-550 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 46.2       & Campana 2001, 134  \\
7   & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 67.3       & Campana 2001, 144  \\
8   & House (Farm) & 600-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 44.3       & Campana 2001, 132  \\
9   & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 47         & Campana 2001, 135  \\
10  & House        & 510-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 42.2       & Campana 2001, 95   \\
11  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 42.3       & Campana 2001, 95   \\
12  & House (Farm) & 510-480 BC & 480-330 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 56         & Cenni 2010, 103    \\
13  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 47.2       & Campana 2001, 98   \\
14  & House        & 630-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 71         & Campana 2001, 109  \\
15  & House (Farm) & 0          & 350-330 BC & 1 & 0          & 1   & 47.1       & Campana 2001, 97   \\
16  & House (Farm) & 580-480 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 35.2       & Cenni 2010, 90     \\
17  & House        & 580-480 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 62.1       & Cenni 2010, 111    \\
18  & House        & 580-480 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 62.2       & Cenni 2010, 111    \\
19  & House        & 510-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 37         & Campana 2001, 93   \\
20  & House        & 630-550 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 84         & Campana 2001, 157  \\
21  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 112        & Campana 2001, 168  \\
22  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 121.2      & Campana 2001, 175  \\
23  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 109.2      & Campana 2013, 133  \\
24  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 114        & Campana 2013, 135  \\
25  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 166        & Campana 2013, 155  \\
26  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 108        & Campana 2013, 132  \\
27  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 111.2      & Campana 2013, 134  \\
28  & House (Farm) & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 109.1      & Campana 2013, 133  \\
29  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 97         & Campana 2001, 135  \\
30  & House (Farm) & 0          & 350-330 BC & 1 & 0          & 1   & 113.1      & Campana 2001, 169  \\
31  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 75         & Cenni 2010, 118    \\
32  & House        & 630-550 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 83         & Campana 2001, 157  \\
33  & House        & 630-580 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 25.1       & Campana 2001, 88   \\
34  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 26         & Campana 2001, 89   \\
35  & House        & 630-550 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 86         & Campana 2001, 158  \\
36  & House        & 630-550 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 102.3      & Campana 2001, 164  \\
37  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 52.1       & Campana 2001, 136  \\
38  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 15         & Cenni 2010, 75     \\
39  & House        & 630-500    & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 16         & Cenni 2010, 75     \\
40  & House        & 650-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 0.85714286 & 0   & 28.3       & Cenni 2010, 84     \\
41  & House (Farm) & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 0.85714286 & 0   & 28.1       & Cenni 2010, 85     \\
42  & House (Farm) & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 0.85714286 & 0   & 28.2       & Cenni 2010, 85     \\
43  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 59.1       & Campana 2001, 139  \\
44  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 120.3      & Campana 2001, 175  \\
45  & House        & 580-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 68         & Campana 2001, 145  \\
46  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 124.1      & Campana 2001, 176  \\
47  & House        & 0          & 400-330 BC & 1 & 0.71428571 & 1   & 124.2      & Campana 2001, 177  \\
48  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 140        & Cenni 2010, 163    \\
49  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 49.1       & Cenni 2010, 99     \\
50  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 49.4       & Cenni 2010, 100    \\
51  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 49.5       & Cenni 2010, 100    \\
52  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 51.1       & Cenni 2010, 101    \\
53  & House        & 630-480 BC & 480-330 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 53.2       & Cenni 2010, 102    \\
54  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 55.2       & Cenni 2010, 102    \\
55  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 114.3      & Campana 2001, 170  \\
56  & House (Farm) & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 114.1      & Campana 2001, 170  \\
57  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 162.1      & Campana 2001, 193  \\
58  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 183.1      & Cenni 2010, 196    \\
59  & House        & 0          & 400-330 BC & 1 & 0          & 1   & 176.1      & Cenni 2010, 194    \\
60  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 1   & 69.2       & Campana 2001, 108  \\
61  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 69.3       & Campana 2001, 108  \\
62  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 1   & 69.4       & Campana 2001, 108  \\
63  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 69.1       & Campana 2001, 108  \\
64  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   &            & Campana 2001, 108  \\
65  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 101.4      & Cenni 2010, 136    \\
66  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 101.5      & Cenni 2010, 136    \\
68  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 60.1       & Cenni 2010, 107    \\
69  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 77.1       & Cenni 2010, 120    \\
70  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 77.2       & Cenni 2010, 121    \\
71  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 161.2      & Cenni 2010, 185    \\
72  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 161.1      & Cenni 2010, 185    \\
73  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 120.3      & Campana 2001, 175  \\
74  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 105.2      & Cenni 2010, 138    \\
75  & Palace       & 630-530 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 10         & Campana 2001, 113  \\
76  & House        & 510-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 139        & Campana 2001, 184  \\
77  & House        & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 157        & Campana 2001, 192  \\
78  & House        & 630-480 BC & 480-330 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 159        & Campana 2001, 192  \\
79  & House        & 630-480 BC & 480-330 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 160        & Campana 2001, 192  \\
80  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 23.6       & Campana 2001, 87   \\
81  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 23.7       & Campana 2001, 87   \\
82  & House (Farm) & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 23.1       & Campana 2001, 85   \\
83  & House (Farm) & 630-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 23.2       & Campana 2001, 86   \\
84  & House        & 600-500 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 23.2       & Campana 2001, 86   \\
85  & House        & 630-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 23.4       & Campana 2001, 88   \\
86  & House        & 630-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 23.3       & Campana 2001, 88   \\
87  & House        & 630-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 23.5       & Campana 2001, 88   \\
88  & House        & 630-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 23.8       & Campana 2001, 88   \\
89  & House        & 630-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 23.9       & Campana 2001, 88   \\
90  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 43         & Campana 2001, 96   \\
91  & House        & 510-480 BC & 480-330 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 8.1        & Cenni 2010, 69     \\
92  & House        & 510-480 BC & 480-330 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 8.2        & Cenni 2010, 69     \\
93  & House        & 0          & 480-330 BC & 1 & 0          & 1   & 211.11     & Cenni 2010, 217    \\
94  & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 100        & Campana 2001, 163  \\
95  & House        & 580-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 92.1       & Campana 2001, 161  \\
96  & House        & 0          & 400-330 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 65.1       & Campana 2001, 142  \\
97  & House        & 580-480 BC & 480-450 BC & 1 & 1          & 0.3 & 66.3       & Campana 2001, 143  \\
98  & House (Farm) & 580-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 116.2      & Campana 2001, 172  \\
99  & House (Farm) & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 116.3      & Campana 2001, 172  \\
100 & House        & 600-480 BC & 480-400 BC & 1 & 1          & 1   & 50.1       & Campana 2001, 100  \\
101 & House        & 630-580 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 50.2       & Campana 2001, 100  \\
102 & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 133.1      & Cenni 2010, 159    \\
103 & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 133.2      & Cenni 2010, 159    \\
104 & House        & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 59.3       & Campana 2001, 104  \\
105 & House (Farm) & 630-500 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 58.1       & Campana 2001, 103  \\
106 & House (Farm) & 630-510 BC & 0          & 1 & 1          & 0   & 58.2       & Campana 2001, 103 
\end{longtable}
```

I also get this additional warning: 'Misplaced alignment tab character &'.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: load the longtable package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: "Misplaced alignment tab character &" is not a warning (something may be wrong, but no break the  compilation), but a fatal error (=no PDF) and it mean exactly what it said. As you can see, the "&" in your table is used as a  align the tabs, i.e, and so it should be only in `tabular`-like environments as `longtable`. BTW, a chunk of code often do not help at all to guess the source of the problem and this one  of theses cases. Take your time to  understand that is a good [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and why we obsessively demand it.